# Joint vs Conditional Probability Question From Data

Tags: probability

If I have data from New York that the percentage of people who are sick is 68%. And I want to set up a probability schema. Is Data from a location a joint probability or a conditional one. This is important since I have different locations.

So is it Pr(Sick|Location) = 0.68, or is it Pr(Sick,Location) = 0.68
I think its a conditional probability if I get data from a particular location. But could it be a joint?
This is probably a simple question but I'm getting confused.
Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Pr(Sick|Location) because you already know that the datas are from New York

Comment: Thank you this is what I thought

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you formulate it. If you are looking at it as estimating a distribution of “Sick” (which I believe you are), then it would be a conditional probability.

However, if you are trying to estimate a joint distribution on “Sick” and “Location”, then it would be a joint probability.

Comment: it should be dependent on how the datas are taken, right? If I know the people I'm testing are from New York then it's conditional otherwise if I pick at random a person in say All USA then it's joint, right?